# How to access static file on server from NextJS 13.5 Public folder that was generated during build time?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, next.js13

I am running a post build script that generates a file `pagination.json` into `public` folder.

This is happening on Vercel, during build time. `npm run build && npm run generate-pagination` is the custom build command that does it.

In Vercel, project, source, output tab I see that pagination.json was generated.

[image: see the second last file pagination.json]

moreover I can access the pagination.json file from [SITE_URL]/pagination.json via browser.

I just cant seem to access it via code in the server during run time, as I have to read this file to decide what to return to the user. Could anyone please help me understand what's going on? what can I do here?

below is the function I am using to read the file with argument `"./public/pagination.json"`:

```js
export async function readFile(localPath: string): Promise<string> {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), localPath);
  try {
    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
    return fileContent;
  } catch (error) {
    const fileError: FileError = {
      message: getErrorMessage(error),
    };
    throw fileError;
  }
}
```

it says no file found at `/var/task/public/pagination.json`

`NextJS 13.5.4`

I updated my NextJS config to following:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    outputFileTracingIncludes: {
      "/*": ["./public/pagination.json"],
      "/*": ["./content/**/*.mdx"],
    },
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

but no luck.